# Sweave to R markdown file conversion - code or converters available?

Tags: r, sweave, r-markdown

I am not sure if this type of question complies with the SO rules for well-defined questions ;) ... anyway:

I want to convert several R Sweave files (`.Rnw`) to R markdown files (`.Rmd`). Jeromy Anglin has posted on this matter [here](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.de/2012/06/converting-sweave-latex-to-knitr-latex.html) but there is no code supplied. I tried to use `pandoc`, but of course `pandoc` cannot handle the chunk tags and inline code tags correctly.

**Consclusion**: I guess I will have do write some code to parse my `.Rnw` files to prepare them for `pandoc` conversion. Thus my questions:

1. Is there a better way to go?
2. Does someone by chance have code
   available that will do the job?

TIA

Comment: `knitr::Sweave2knitr()` - is that what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I want to convert .Rnw (tex) to .Rmd (markdown). What the function does is to convert .Rnw (tex, Sewave syntax) to .Rnw (tex, knitr syntax). But this will already be a helpful first step when moving from .Rnw (Sweave syntax) to R markdown!

Comment: Do you understand that implies converting tex to markdown, which is not possible since TeX has far more possibilities than markdown ?

Answer (score 5):

As @Karl commented, LaTeX --> markdown is not a trivial conversion as there are far more options and environments available in LaTeX compared to markdown. You are probably best off working with something like [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demos.html) (see Demo #5). Basically, instead of doing

.Rnw --> .Rmd --> .md

you would do

.Rnw --> .tex --> .md

with pandoc. If you really want to go from .Rnw --> .Rmd, you may want to check out the [pander](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#creating-pandoc-documents) package to write a function to extract code chunks, convert the remaining LaTeX content to markdown, and then re-insert the code chunks into the markdown document.